# Nodejs example for encode .ply to .drc

Tags: javascript, node.js, 3d

Looking for example code to convert 3d .ply to .drc (https://github.com/google/draco) compression in nodejs or javascript. Following draco3d document able to build command line tool and successfully convert ply to drc. But not sure how to achieve the same programmatically using nodejs or javascript solution. Examples are not clear in this below official documentation.

https://github.com/google/draco/tree/master/javascript/npm/draco3d

TIA